# How to show monthly graphs on each node's index page in Munin

Tags: munin, rrdtool

I am running Munin 2.0.73 on FreeBSD 13.2. The HTML files generated by Munin only show daily graphs ("by day") and weekly graphs ("by week") on a node's index page (`http://localhost/munin/localdomain/localhost.localdomain/index.html`). For example:

[image]

I can see the "by month" and "by year" graph when I click on `http://localhost/munin/localdomain/localhost.localdomain/munin_stats.html`, but I want to see them on the index.html page instead.

How do I configure Munin to show monthly graphs ("by month") in addition to the daily and weekly graphs on the `http://localhost/munin/localdomain/localhost.localdomain/index.html` page?

Comment: What do you see if you click on any of these graphs?

Comment: @sotirov A broken webpage. I decided not to use Munin's dynamic/zoomable graphs, so I did not configure Munin and my web server to handle CGI scripts. Do the dynamic graphs show an entire month of data? I would prefer the static graphs (as shown in the question's screenshot) to show a "by month" graph instead of relying on dynamic graphs.

Comment: I am using Munin 2.0.73 on several Ubuntu and Debian servers. When I click on the graph, it opens a new page with 4 static graphs by day, by week, by month, by year. Like this: https://i.imgur.com/z9tpKrr.png In my case the Munin processing time opens `http://localhost/munin/localdomain/localhost.localdomain/munin_stats.html`. This is what you want, right? btw, it works without the CGI enabled.

Comment: @sotirov Sorry, I was mistaken. I do see what is shown in your screenshot when I visit `http://localhost/munin/localdomain/localhost.localdomain/munin_stats.html`. I guess my question is how to show the "by month" graph on `http://localhost/munin/localdomain/localhost.localdomain/index.html` along with the "by day" and "by week" graphs. I have edited the question to clarify my intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by editing Munin template files. What you need is in `munin-nodeview.tmpl`. In my case the file is in: `/etc/munin/templates/munin-nodeview.tmpl` but depending on your configuration, it can be somewhere else.

The original file look like this:

```
<TMPL_INCLUDE NAME="partial/head.tmpl">
<body>
<TMPL_INCLUDE NAME="partial/logo_navigation.tmpl">
<div id="main">
<TMPL_INCLUDE NAME="partial/navigation.tmpl">
<div id="content">
<h2>Node view</h2>
<TMPL_LOOP NAME="CATEGORIES">
<h3 id="<TMPL_VAR ESCAPE="HTML" NAME="NAME">"><TMPL_VAR ESCAPE="HTML" NAME="NAME"></h3>
<table>
        <TMPL_LOOP NAME="SERVICES">
                <tr><td><TMPL_VAR ESCAPE="HTML" NAME="NAME"></td></tr><tr><td>
                <a href="<TMPL_VAR NAME="URLX">">
                <img class="i<TMPL_IF NAME="STATE_WARNING">warn</TMPL_IF><TMPL_IF NAME="STATE_CRITICAL">crit</TMPL_IF>"
                 src="<TMPL_VAR NAME="IMGDAY">"
                 alt="<TMPL_VAR ESCAPE="HTML" NAME="NAME">"
         <TMPL_IF NAME="IMGDAYWIDTH">width="<TMPL_VAR NAME="IMGDAYWIDTH">" </TMPL_IF>
                 <TMPL_IF NAME="IMGDAYHEIGHT">height="<TMPL_VAR NAME="IMGDAYHEIGHT">"</TMPL_IF>/>
                </a></td>
        <td><a href="<TMPL_VAR NAME="URLX">">
                <img class="i<TMPL_IF NAME="STATE_WARNING">warn</TMPL_IF><TMPL_IF NAME="STATE_CRITICAL">crit</TMPL_IF>"
                 src="<TMPL_VAR NAME="IMGWEEK">"
                 alt="<TMPL_VAR ESCAPE="HTML" NAME="NAME">"
                 <TMPL_IF NAME="IMGWEEKWIDTH">width="<TMPL_VAR NAME="IMGWEEKWIDTH">" </TMPL_IF>
                 <TMPL_IF NAME="IMGWEEKHEIGHT">height="<TMPL_VAR NAME="IMGWEEKHEIGHT">"</TMPL_IF>/>
                </a></td>
                </tr>
        </TMPL_LOOP>
</table>
</TMPL_LOOP>
</div>
</div>
<TMPL_INCLUDE NAME="partial/footer.tmpl">
</body>
</html>
```

Replace it with:

```
<TMPL_INCLUDE NAME="partial/head.tmpl">
<body>
<TMPL_INCLUDE NAME="partial/logo_navigation.tmpl">
<div id="main">
<TMPL_INCLUDE NAME="partial/navigation.tmpl">
<div id="content">
<h2>Node view</h2>
<TMPL_LOOP NAME="CATEGORIES">
<h3 id="<TMPL_VAR ESCAPE="HTML" NAME="NAME">"><TMPL_VAR ESCAPE="HTML" NAME="NAME"></h3>
<table>
        <TMPL_LOOP NAME="SERVICES">
                <tr><td><TMPL_VAR ESCAPE="HTML" NAME="NAME"></td></tr><tr><td>
                <a href="<TMPL_VAR NAME="URLX">">
                <img class="i<TMPL_IF NAME="STATE_WARNING">warn</TMPL_IF><TMPL_IF NAME="STATE_CRITICAL">crit</TMPL_IF>"
                 src="<TMPL_VAR NAME="IMGDAY">"
                 alt="<TMPL_VAR ESCAPE="HTML" NAME="NAME">"
         <TMPL_IF NAME="IMGDAYWIDTH">width="<TMPL_VAR NAME="IMGDAYWIDTH">" </TMPL_IF>
                 <TMPL_IF NAME="IMGDAYHEIGHT">height="<TMPL_VAR NAME="IMGDAYHEIGHT">"</TMPL_IF>/>
                </a></td>
        <td><a href="<TMPL_VAR NAME="URLX">">
                <img class="i<TMPL_IF NAME="STATE_WARNING">warn</TMPL_IF><TMPL_IF NAME="STATE_CRITICAL">crit</TMPL_IF>"
                 src="<TMPL_VAR NAME="IMGWEEK">"
                 alt="<TMPL_VAR ESCAPE="HTML" NAME="NAME">"
                 <TMPL_IF NAME="IMGWEEKWIDTH">width="<TMPL_VAR NAME="IMGWEEKWIDTH">" </TMPL_IF>
                 <TMPL_IF NAME="IMGWEEKHEIGHT">height="<TMPL_VAR NAME="IMGWEEKHEIGHT">"</TMPL_IF>/>
                </a></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><a href="<TMPL_VAR NAME="URLX">">
                <img class="i<TMPL_IF NAME="STATE_WARNING">warn</TMPL_IF><TMPL_IF NAME="STATE_CRITICAL">crit</TMPL_IF>"
                 src="<TMPL_VAR NAME="IMGMONTH">"
                 alt="<TMPL_VAR ESCAPE="HTML" NAME="NAME">"
                 <TMPL_IF NAME="IMGMONTHWIDTH">width="<TMPL_VAR NAME="IMGMONTHWIDTH">" </TMPL_IF>
                 <TMPL_IF NAME="IMGMONTHHEIGHT">height="<TMPL_VAR NAME="IMGMONTHHEIGHT">"</TMPL_IF>/>
                </a></td>
                <td><a href="<TMPL_VAR NAME="URLX">">
                <img class="i<TMPL_IF NAME="STATE_WARNING">warn</TMPL_IF><TMPL_IF NAME="STATE_CRITICAL">crit</TMPL_IF>"
                 src="<TMPL_VAR NAME="IMGYEAR">"
                 alt="<TMPL_VAR ESCAPE="HTML" NAME="NAME">"
                 <TMPL_IF NAME="IMGYEARWIDTH">width="<TMPL_VAR NAME="IMGYEARWIDTH">" </TMPL_IF>
                 <TMPL_IF NAME="IMGYEARHEIGHT">height="<TMPL_VAR NAME="IMGYEARHEIGHT">"</TMPL_IF>/>
                </a></td>
        </tr>
        </TMPL_LOOP>
</table>
</TMPL_LOOP>
</div>
</div>
```

I basically added one new row `<tr>` with two new columns `<td>` and used `MONTH` and `YEAR` instead of `DAY` and `WEEK`.

**After you make these changes, you will have to wait about 5 minutes until munin recreates the new files. Be patient!**

This is the final result:
[image: munin node screenshot]

Comment: Thank you! In FreeBSD 13.2, the template file is at `/usr/local/etc/munin/templates/munin-nodeview.tmpl`.